# Large latency when thread interrupted using hibernate and c3p0

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I am seeing these warnings in our logs, and when I do, I see larger-than-normal latencies on transactions in our database. I've scoured the internet looking for more information.

```
2014-12-01 18:14:03,866 [BoundedFuturePool-2] WARN  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - {} com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@2f18b0cb -- an attempt to checkout a resource was interrupted, and the pool is still live: some other thread must have either interrupted the Thread attempting checkout!
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1414)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:74)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.setReadOnly(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(DataSourceUtils.java:155)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:508)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:329)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at com.twitter.amplify.videoediting.data.TranscodingDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$696749fa.getTranscodeInfo(<generated>)
at com.twitter.amplify.videoediting.GetTranscodeInfoHandler$$anonfun$7.apply(GetTranscodeInfoHandler.scala:78)
at com.twitter.amplify.videoediting.GetTranscodeInfoHandler$$anonfun$7.apply(GetTranscodeInfoHandler.scala:78)
at com.twitter.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:13)
at com.twitter.util.ExecutorServiceFuturePool$$anon$2.run(FuturePool.scala:112)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at com.twitter.amplify.util.LocalExecutorService$1.call(LocalExecutorService.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is our configuration object.

```
Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 5, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 2u120u951sgpypjpvvovo|73f2f11, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 2u120u951sgpypjpvvovo|73f2f11, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 0, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://db-hat-rw-master-001.global-db.twttr.net/amplify?defaultFetchSize=200, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 60, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 60, maxPoolSize -> 200, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 0, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> select 1, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> true, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 300, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]]
```

Thank you for your help!
Max

Answer (score 1):

So, the warning is telling you as much as c3p0 knows directly: a client Thread seeking to check out a Connection -- and wait()ing to get ahold of one -- had interrupt() called on it, forcing the Thread to break from its wait(). The Thread that was blocked is an application Thread (it's a scala app, calling something in com.twitter.amplify.videoediting.GetTranscodeInfoHandler). Most likely, some other part of the application watches these Threads and interrupt()s them if they hang. If this is so, it's the latency you are observing that is the core problem. Your Connection pool is maxed out, either because it has hit `maxPoolSize` or it has not but needs to acquire more Connections from the DBMS. Threads get stuck wait()ing for Connections, then they wait for too long and get killed by an external monitor.

Your `maxPoolSize` of 200 is pretty big, but obviously big must be judged relative to demand. Maybe you have more than 200 simultaneous client Threads. (You can monitor this stuff by JMX, by the way, to see pretty directly whether your pool is hitting its ceiling.)

But my guess (and it is only that) is that your problem has to do with failing to scale the pool up rapidly enough. For an application at the scale you are running, c3p0's default Thread pool size (quaintly described by a configuration parameter called `numHelperThreads`, sorry about that) is way too small at 3. The first thing I'd do is ramp that up to 10 or 20. If that doesn't solve your problem, you might check JMX to see if you in fact are bumping up against your DataSource's `maxPoolSize` of 200. (If you are, you can raise that too, although eventually there will be diminishing returns as Thread contention bites.) You might also monitor `numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser`, which should also be available by JMX.

But I'd start with `numHelperThreads`. It's way-too-small value may well be the problem.

Comment: Ok, I will definitely bump up the numHelperThreads. If the problem is indeed scaling the pool fast enough, do you think that bumping the acquireIncrement from 5 will also be helpful? Thanks!

Comment: yes, a larger `acquireIncrement` might be helpful! would reduce the frequency with which new Connection acquisitions are required, and that seems to be your bottleneck.

Comment: can you please comment on Andy's answer below?

Comment: It's certainly true that if the pool is close()ed, client Threads would be interrupted, leading to the message you see. But that's usually be a shutdown glitch, your app is being shutdown and maybe you (or your middleware) call close() on the c3p0 DataSource while it still has clients wait()ing for a Connection. Then, sure, you'd see the message you see in logs of the shutdown process. But the pool isn't closed so easily.

Comment: The worst that `ConnectionEventListener.connectionErrorOccurred(...)` would do is reset the pool, which would not cause wait()ers to be interrupted. (The source file for that is C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java, not BasicResourcePool.java.) The `BasicResourcePool.close()` method is never called in any kind of loop (that would be pathological, wouldn't do very much, since the body of the method protected by the `broken` flag to ensure the method is idempotent.

Comment: The main way in practice you might see a c3p0 DataSource interrupt its own waiters because of a resource pool shutdown is if you are updating c3p0 config parameters programmatically on a running DataSource, e.g. increasing the maxPoolSize on the fly by calling `dataSource.setMaxPoolSize( 250 )` within a live application. That would force the DataSource to close() and replace its resource pools (whose configs are immutable), and might provoke self-interrupt()s. If you are doing that (changing c3p0 config on live, busy DataSources), that could cause your issue.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that our max # connections is 200, but normal traffic patterns are usually under 20. Does your advise apply equally with usually fewer connections? (While I've not seen it go much above 20, I've not been looking when we are seeing the increased latencies.)

Comment: Assuming there's some external monitor interrupting your Threads when they are slow (again, that's just a guess!), then it's a race between Connection acquisition and your time limit. Things that could slow Connection acquisition are 1) slow DBMS; 2) slow network btw app & DBMS; 3) saturated Thread pool delaying Connection acquisition. [Latency in this scenario is likely cause more than effect.] A less busy pool makes (3) less likely, but not impossible, depending. You might examine whether you are overstressing with e.g. too frequent asynchronous Connection tests or Connection expirations.

Answer (score 1):

This exception will always occur when a thread enters BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable and sleeps at line 1414 and another thread enters BasicResourcePool.close( boolean ) line 1225 when broken == false.

In this situation thread inside close will call Thread.interrupt() on the awaiting threads.

See this code, line 1276. It is interupting the threads sleeping at line 1441 of BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable.

```
        for (Iterator ii = acquireWaiters.iterator(); ii.hasNext(); )
            ((Thread) ii.next()).interrupt();
```

Its important to note, that AwaitAvailable is called prelimCheckoutResource - line 568, which is synchronized. Thus when it sleeps at line 1414, it releases the lock, which allows another Thread to enter close, which is also synchronized.

Thus once Thread.interrupt is called inside close, none of the sleeping threads can actually wake up until after the interrupting thread in BasicResourcePool.close() has returned from the synchronized block and released the lock, because returning from .wait() requires the thread to re-acquire the lock.

ie. Once another thread enters a synchronized block, your sleeping thread wont wake up once the timeout expires or indeed to handle the InterruptedException until the other thread exits the synchronized block.

Thus **if** a situation exists when a synchronized method that calls close from a loop, your thread will not be able to return until that other thread releases the lock.

It's worth mentioning that BasicResourcePool.connectionErrorOccurred() calls the synchronized method BasicResourcePool.resetPool() and this method in a loop, calls close, which will interrupt your thread, but block it from awaking until after resetPool releases the lock.

Just speculating that this is occurring, but if it did, it would cause the exception you see and may also explain the latency.